# Simple partial derivative question (Laplacian, heat equation)

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

A question about a derivation involving the time derivative of the heat equation expressed in terms of eigenvectors of the Laplace operator. The derivation appears in the book *Diffusion Driven Wavelet Design* on p.31, however the book is not needed to understand this post. In fact I believe this is just a basic calculus question.

The derivation:
The solution $u(x,t)$ of the heat equation can be expanded in the basis formed by the eigenvectors $\phi_k(x)$ of the Laplacian,
$$
   u(x,t) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k(t) \phi_k(x)
$$
The derivative of this with respect to time is
$$
  \frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\partial c_k(t)}{\partial t} \phi_k(x)
$$
This is the step I do not follow:
$$ 
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k(t) \Delta \phi_k(x)
$$
where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator (in fact the Laplacian on the manifold, but I believe this distinction does not matter)
$$
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} - c_k(t) \lambda_k \phi_k(x)
$$

So, the step I miss is evidently $\frac{\partial c_k(t)}{\partial t} = c_k(t) \Delta$.

Comment: $u$ satisfy the Heat equation so $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \Delta u = \sum c_k \Delta \phi_k$.

Comment: Yes, that answers it. Thank you.